# Why is the net torque 0 when pushing a block across a table?

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction, torque, moment

[image]

The way I see it, when I push a block across a table, taking care to push in line with its centre of mass or just below, the object should topple over because the friction should create a (clockwise, in the case of the diagram) torque about the object that is not balanced out by anything else.

However, there must clearly be another force acting on the block above or below its centre of mass with exactly enough of a magnitude to balance out the torque caused by friction, hence resulting in a net torque of 0.

What is this mystery force?

Comment: As the block starts to (possibly) topple, what is the centre of (possible) rotation?

Comment: It's the centre of mass, right?

Comment: By the way, before you talk about the concept of _torque_, first you need to specify your origin which you are measuring the torque.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion arises because you are thinking of *one* force acting from the floor. In reality there is a pressure distribution on the contact that is often approximated by *two* forces *A* and *B*

[image: pic]

They arrange themselves such that the net torque is zero *because the block is not rotationally accelerating*. If you push a block over an edge and let it fall the net torque will not be zero and the block will tilt.

Comment: So is B greater than A to stop the object falling over?

Comment: @Pancake_Senpai yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is a kinematic constraint: if $F$ is not too strong, the block must remain horizontal. This constraint is imposed by the normal reaction of the table: in your diagram, it acts on the right side of the block, pushing upward and balancing the torque you mentionned.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the accepted answer, the frictional forces have no affect on the tipping point, except in limiting the size of the applied force before slipping occurs.

When the box tips, it does so by rotating about the leading bottom corner of the box.  The rest of the bottom of the box is ***just*** lifting off the surface;  the only normal force and friction force are acting at that point.
Since the force of friction and the normal force both act through the point of rotation, their contribution to the rotational torque is zero.

A ***clockwise*** torque is exerted by the applied force, multiplied by the height at which the force is applied.  To safely move a filing cabinet, push horizontally close to the floor;  to tip it over, push near the top.

A ***counter clockwise*** torque is exerted by the force of gravity acting downward through the centre of mass.  If the file cabinet drawer contents are towards the front of each drawer, pushing on the front of the cabinet is the safer way to move it.

The distribution of mass vertically has no effect initially on the tipping point.  However, once tipping starts, the rotation moves the centre of mass horizontally closer to the point of rotation, reducing the counter clockwise torque.  A high CofM moves faster, increasing the net tipping moment.

Comment: This is not "*contrary to the accepted answer*". You are explaining why it doesn't rotate about the corner, and the accepted answer about the CoM. Both are correct.